# Using Azure Service Management REST API as a registered Active Directory app

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

We have an application that talks to Azure Service Management API (management.azure.com) to automatically upload API definitions in API Management.

As authentication method, we created an "App Registration" in Azure Active Directory, and assigned a secret. So we use the client ID and secret of this application. This method is described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview

The token is retrieved using MSAL:

```
private static async Task<string> GetAccesToken(AzureADApplicationCredentials adApplicationCredentials)
{
    var scopes = new string[] { @"https://management.azure.com/.default" };

    var app = Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
       .Create(adApplicationCredentials.ClientId)
       .WithClientSecret(adApplicationCredentials.Secret)
       .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{adApplicationCredentials.DirectoryId}"))
       .Build();

    var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

    return result?.AccessToken;
}
```

Using this authentication, we can successfully get a list of API's, but the call to add an api to a service fails with the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client 'f42...' with object id 'f42...' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/write' over scope '/subscriptions/27e.../resourceGroups/OurResouceName/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/OurServiceName/apis/7c6...' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
    }
}
```

What i have tried:

- I have noticed that i can assign permissions in the "API Permissions" section of the App registration, but i am only able to assign the "user_impersonation" permission for "Azure Service Management", which i dont think is actually needed in my scenario.
- I am using the https://management.azure.com/.default scope, as suggested by the documentation. I think i should be able to pass in a different scope than .default, but i cannot find any further information on this.
  I did encounter this page, which lists all the permissions:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftapimanagement
  I have tried using there values as scopes (Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/write etc ...) to no avail.

Any thoughts on how i can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, the reason that you encounter is error is due to that your Azure AD application has no write permission on your APIM scope , seems it has read permission only.

I can repro your issue while I register a new Azure AD App with no permission assigned.

To solve this issue ,just go to your APIM , click "Access control (IAM)" and click "Add" to assign a role with write permission to your Azure AD application ,such as "Contributor" ,save and get a new access token will solve this issue. 
[image]

For more info about Azure access control , you can refer to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) . 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting. I can read but not write, so i guess for users not in that list there is a default role?